# Proving a limit equals $0$ using a given theorem

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> Let $a$ be a real number. Prove that if
>
> $$\lim_{(x, y) \to (0,0)} \frac{ax}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} = 0,$$
>
> then we must have $a = 0$.

I would like to solve this using the following fact:

> $$\lim_{(x, y) \to (x_0, y_0)} \frac{f(x,y) - \psi(x,y)}{\sqrt{(x -
>  x_0)^2 + (y - y_0)^2}} = 0$$
>
> where $\psi(x, y) = f(x_0, y_0) + f_{x}(x_0, y_0)(x - x_0) + f_y(y -
>  y_0)$.

I'm pretty sure this is the right way to do it, because the exercise just before this one (which I solved) was to show $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0,0)} \frac{ax^2 + bxy + y^2}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} = 0$. This was done by defining $f(x, y) = ax^2 + bxy + y^2$, and just plugging it into the fact above (we end up getting $\psi(x, y) = 0$).

I can't figure this problem out, though. I tried defining $f(x, y) = ax$, and I got $\psi(x, y) = ax$, which didn't get me anywhere. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $a$ is any nonzero number and the limit exists then
$$
\lim\frac{ax}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}=a\lim\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}.
$$
Next, consider the sequence $x_{n}=1/n$ and $y_{n}=0$. It follows
that
$$
\frac{x_{n}}{\sqrt{x_{n}^{2}+y_{n}^{2}}}=\frac{1/n}{\sqrt{(1/n)^{2}}}=1
$$
and hence
$$
\lim\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}\neq0.
$$
Therefore, $a$ must be zero.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x,y):= \frac{ax}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$ . For $x \ne 0$ we have

$f(x,x)=\frac{ax}{\sqrt{2}|x|}.$

Hence $ \lim_{x \to 0+}f(x,x)=\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $ \lim_{x \to 0-}f(x,x)=-\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Conclusion: if $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0,0)} \frac{ax}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} = 0$, then $\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}=-\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}$ and threrfore $a=0.$

Comment: You have $ \lim_{x \to 0+}f(x,x)=\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}} =0.$ Why not just say therefore $a=0?$